# Avoiding trailing newline in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline

I'm working on a project right now and as one of the features, I'm supposed to traverse through a list and output the items in different lines.

The code looks something like this:

```py
dictionary = {'key0': sorted([item + "\n" 
              for item in mylist}])

print(x[1]) for x in dictionary.items()
```

However, this leaves a trailing newline every time.

Would something like this work?

```py
string = ''

otherlist = sorted([item + "\n" for item in mylist])

for i in range(len(otherlist)):
    string.join(sorted[i])

string.rstrip()

print(string)
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.join`:

```
print("".join(x[1] for x in dictionary.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the newline in your list comprehension, simply join the list with newlines.

```
lines = '\n'.join(otherlist)
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a `list.join` method. Maybe you meant `'\n'.join(otherlist)`?

Comment: @TrebledJ you're correct, it's been a while since I've been writing python daily ;)